# How to use AND OR operator in hibernate Detached criteria query

Tags: hibernate

I have a requirement to use AND/OR operator to hibernate detached criteria queries.
I want to emulate SQL eqivalent to:

```
Select * from myTable where city in ( X, Y ) OR city in (A,B);
```

// Note i need to use multiple 'In'  here

How to create citeria query to use 'OR' operator.

Something like

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(
    myClass.class)
   .add(Property.forName("city").in(X,Y));
criteria.**Or**(add(Property.forName("city").in(X,Y));
```

Unfortunatly there is no OR method in criteria , only add there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Restrictions.conjunction()` and `Restrictions.disjunction()` to create the hierarchy of conditions.

Look [here - section 15.2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/RestrictionsDisjunction.htm)

---

EDIT:

I suppose that your code `Property.forName("city").in(X,Y))` is correct ( I don't remember this clausule )

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(
    myClass.class)
   .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
       .add( Property.forName("city").in(X,Y) )
       .add(Property.forName("city").in(X,Y)  )
   );
```

Comment: Thanks Gaim. The document are not very revealing but i think i got the idea.  If I'm right:

Comment: Restrictions.conjunction() is for ADD operator and Restrictions.disjunction() for OR operator?

Comment: @Alexs Yes, all restrictions added into conjunction are joined with AND operator and all restrictions added into disjunction are joined with OR. If it is not relevant then sorry, I didn't understand your question

Comment: I am trying to use disjunction with DetachedCriteria as per example,  i provided in my question:
   but its throwing error as cannot be used for DetachedCriteria !

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(myClass.class);
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();

 criteria.add(Property.forName("city").in(X,Y));
disjunction.add(criteria)
I acatualy need to OR these two IN statements (pseudocode)
criteria.add(Property.forName("city").in(X,Y)  
  OR
criteria.add(Property.forName("city").in(A,B));

Comment: @Alexs look at edit ( it is not tested but should be correct )

Comment: Thanks Gaim   It looks like working but Instead of OR operator its still using AND operator, though i have used disjunction() !!
Here is display SQL which is generated.

    select * from myClass 
    where
            (
                this_.City in (
                    ?, ?
                )
        ) 
        and (
            this_.City in (
                ?,?
            )
        )

I wonder Y its using AND operator?

Comment: there are also the aliases ´Restrictions.or()´ and ´Restrictions.and()´ which you can use. check here:http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: @Alexs Are you sure that you have copied the parentheses correctly? You have to call the add method on the disjunction() - it defines the block of disjuncted conditions

Comment: @Gaim   ...My Mistake.. I was adding the wrong way.  I exactly followed your example snippet and it worked :)  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following steps:

Step-1.0: Create Query Criteria

```
Criteria myQueryCrit = session.createCriteria(XYZ.class, "xyz");
```

Step-2.0: For Handling OR conditions of Query:

2.1) First you need to create Disjunction object, say, myQueryDisjunc.

```
Disjunction myQueryDisjunc = Restrictions.disjunction();
```

2.2) Then create the All OR Criterion objects. Like:

```
Criterion xyzName = Restrictions.ilike("xyz.name", "%"+searchStr1+"%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE);

Criterion xyzSpeciality = Restrictions.ilike("xyz.specs", "%"+searchStr1+"%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE);

Criterion xyzServices = Restrictions.ilike("xyz.services", "%"+searchStr1+"%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
```

2.3) Adding all OR Criterions object into myQueryDisjunc

```
myQueryDisjunc.add(xyzName);

myQueryDisjunc.add(xyzSpeciality);

myQueryDisjunc.add(xyzServices);
```

Step-3.0: For Handling AND conditions of Query:

3.1) First you need to create Conjunction object, say, myQueryConjunc.

```
Conjunction myQueryConjunc = Restrictions.conjunction();
```

3.2) Then create the All AND Criterion objects. Like:

```
Criterion xyzLoc = Restrictions.ilike("xyz.locStr", "%"+searchStr2+"%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE);

Criterion xyzZip = Restrictions.ilike("xyz.zipStr", "%"+searchStr3+"%", MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
```

3.3) Adding all AND Criterions object into myQueryConjunc

```
myQueryConjunc.add(xyzLoc);

myQueryConjunc.add(xyzZip);
```

Step-4.0: Now add myQueryDisjunc, myQueryConjunc into myQueryCrit:

```
myQueryCrit.add(myQueryDisjunc);
myQueryCrit.add(myQueryConjunc);
```

Step-5.0: Now add any Result Trnasformer if needed [ optional ]:

```
myQueryCrit.setResultTransformer(
CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Step-6.0: Execute the myQueryCrit by, invoking list() on it.

```
List <myObj> allResults = myQueryCrit.list();
```

Step-7.0: Thats All.